# VueJs - Axios: How to send multiple value in params?

Tags: vuejs2, axios

Can you help me?
I have POST method with body parameter with two value in var product_ids

```
BODY
product_ids = 8|559
customer_type_id = 2
qty_from = 11
sell_price = 10001
```

and it's my axios code

```
createNewPricetiers() {
  this.loading = true
  let headers = {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.accessToken
  }
  let data = {
    product_ids: this.$route.params.id || this.form.variant,
    customer_type_id: this.form.customer,
    qty_from: this.form.qty,
    sell_price: this.form.sellPrice
  }
  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: BASE_API + 'productpricetiers',
    headers: headers,
    data: data
  })
  ...
```

but when it call server, multiple params can't run
just send params `this.$route.params.id`
where is my fault?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `product_ids: \`${this.$route.params.id}|${this.form.variant}\``? The `||` is a boolean "OR" operator

Comment: yes i know, but backend request for body in product_ids is two value with separator

Comment: That's what I figured from your example at the top of your question. So, did you try what I suggested? You could also use `product_ids: this.$route.params.id + '|' + this.form.variant` if you don't like string template literals. Or even `[this.$route.params.id, this.form.variant].join('|')`. It's the same result though

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. You should be creating a pipe-delimited string, not a Boolean expression

Comment: great, it's run thank you @phil. but the both your suggest it string value not integer?

Comment: A pipe-delimited string is by definition, a string. It cannot possibly be an integer

Answer (score 0):

add a default header when using axios.post:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

Comment: What makes you think OP doesn't want JSON? In any case, there's more to do than just setting the `Content-Type` header. See https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Comment: i don't understand, can you give me example

Comment: @dede.brahma if your server-side endpoint accepts JSON, you can ignore this answer completely